# Starting a description on a new line following its heading

Tags: formatting, lists, description

I like the indentation style of a `description` environment; I'd like to use it to summarize each of my thesis chapters. But, I'd like the actual paragraph to start on the *next* line. How can I do this?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
]{microtype}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section*{Summary}
We summarize. 
\begin{description}
  \item[Chapter 1: This is Chapter 1's Quite Significantly Fairly Long Title] \lipsum[1]
  \item[Chapter 2: This is Chapter 2's Quite Significantly Fairly Long Title] \lipsum[2]
\end{description}
That's all for the summary.
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the option `style=nextline` (see section 3.7 Description styles in the [`enumitem` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf)):

```latex
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
]{microtype}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section*{Summary}
We summarize. 
\begin{description}[style=nextline]
  \item[Chapter 1: This is Chapter 1's Quite Significantly Fairly Long Title] \lipsum[1]
  \item[Chapter 2: This is Chapter 2's Quite Significantly Fairly Long Title] \lipsum[2]
\end{description}
That's all for the summary.
\end{document}
```